# Unacceptable TLS certificate trying to run simple GStreamer pipeline

Tags: ssl, gstreamer

I'm trying to run a very GStreamer pipeline on macOS 10.15 provided [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/handy-elements.html?gi-language=c), to play a video from the Internet; however, I get the error "Unacceptable TLS certificate". I also tried with other video URLs but got the same error for all. The output is the same using `souphttpsrc` instead of `uridecodebin`. See the pipeline and the console output below.

I remember this kind of pipeline working seamlessly on Ubuntu. What could be the reason for this behaviour on macOS, and is there anyway to make the TLS certificate "acceptable"?

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Got context from element 'source': gst.soup.session=context, session=(SoupSession)NULL, force=(boolean)false;
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstSoupHTTPSrc:source: Secure connection setup failed.
Additional debug info:
../ext/soup/gstsouphttpsrc.c(1383): gst_soup_http_src_parse_status (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstSoupHTTPSrc:source:
Unacceptable TLS certificate (6), URL: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm, Redirect to: (NULL)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstSoupHTTPSrc:source: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(3127): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstSoupHTTPSrc:source:
streaming stopped, reason error (-5)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefindelement0: Stream doesn't contain enough data.
Additional debug info:
../plugins/elements/gsttypefindelement.c(988): gst_type_find_element_chain_do_typefinding (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefindelement0:
Can't typefind stream
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ..
```